# Java Thread Design

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am trying to do a sample utility java code that I need to implement using Threads but I am not sure
if what I did is optimal.

Here is my use case:
The main thread will create a child thread.  The child thread will create two other threads (WebCallThread and RestCallThread) that will
call a REST web service.

I used Threads here since it takes some time to retrieve values from the REST calls.. basically the REST services just returns
a list of doubles.

For simplicity sake, I just used Math.random() here just to generate the code...

```
package com.thread;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SampleThreads {
    static List<Double> dblList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static List<Double> statelList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    static boolean webResult = false;
    static boolean restResult = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting ThreadTesting!!!!");
        ChildThread childThread = new ChildThread();;
        childThread.start();

        try {
            childThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(webResult && restResult) {
            System.out.println("Success WebCall!!!!");
            System.out.println(dblList);
            System.out.println(statelList);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Something gone wrong!!!!!");
        }

        System.out.println("Finished ThreadTesting!!!!");
    }

    static class ChildThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Starting ChildThread!!!!");
            WebCallThread webThread = new WebCallThread();
            webThread.start();

            RestCallThread restThread = new RestCallThread();
            restThread.start();

            try {
                webThread.join();
                restThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Finished ChildThread!!!!");
        }

    }

    static class WebCallThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Starting WebCallThread!!!!");
            int ctr =0;
            while(true) {
                if(ctr > 5) {
                    webResult = true;
                    System.out.println("Finished WebCallThread!!!!");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Adding to WebCallThread :: " + ctr);
                dblList.add(Math.random());
                ctr++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class RestCallThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Starting RestCallThread!!!!");
            int ctr =0;
            while(true) {
                if(ctr > 10) {
                    restResult = true;
                    System.out.println("Finished RestCallThread!!!!");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Adding to RestCallThread :: " + ctr);
                statelList.add(Math.random());
                ctr++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I am a bit concern about my checking if the webResult and restResult is okay here or is threadsafe..
What if thread gets interrupted or there is a failure in calling REST service.
So it is okay to assume that the values will not be updated right and I could log a "Something gone wrong!!!!!" message?

```
if(webResult && restResult) {
            System.out.println("Success WebCall!!!!");
            System.out.println(dblList);
            System.out.println(statelList);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Something gone wrong!!!!!");
        }
```

Also, I used variables to hold the returned REST result in my Main Thread and I will do processing of the results.  The values of this threads are populated by my REST Web Service Call.

```
static List<Double> dblList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static List<Double> statelList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

I am no Java Thread experts and I just wrote this on the fly.
Could somebody nitpick my code and is there a possibility that it might fail?
I am open to suggestion for better code.

Comment: It was a great question though ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your implementation that I can point out. In the first place using `static` `boolean` variables such as `webResult`, `restResult` is counter intuitive and also error prone. These variables are read and written by multiple Threads, and may lead to race conditions in a concurrent setting. You could rather use a thread coordination mechanism like `CountDownLatch` to achieve the same goal more elegantly.

Another point is that both your threads `WebCallThread` and `RestCallThread` add results into a shared data structure which is used by other threads such as the main `Thread`. This may lead to another race condition. Hence you can use `Callable` instead of `Runnable` here.

Finally creating a new Thread for each request is not a good practice, since thread creation is costly. So you can use an `ExecutorService` and share few Threads from the pool to overcome costs associated with unnecessary thread creation.

At last, but not the least you can get rid of the `ChildThread` and place that simple logic inside the main thread instead.

The improved code with the above suggested changes is given below.

```
public class SampleThreads {
    private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Starting ThreadTesting!!!!");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        try {
            Future<List<Double>> webResponse = executor.submit(new WebCallThread());
            Future<List<Double>> restResponse = executor.submit(new RestCallThread());
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("Success WebCall!!!!");
            System.out.println(webResponse.get());
            System.out.println(restResponse.get());
            System.out.println("Finished ThreadTesting!!!!");
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }

    static class WebCallThread implements Callable<List<Double>> {
        @Override
        public List<Double> call() throws Exception {
            final List<Double> dblList = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("Starting WebCallThread!!!!");
            int ctr = 0;
            while (true) {
                if (ctr > 5) {
                    latch.countDown();
                    System.out.println("Finished WebCallThread!!!!");
                    return dblList;
                }
                System.out.println("Adding to WebCallThread :: " + ctr);
                dblList.add(Math.random());
                ctr++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class RestCallThread implements Callable<List<Double>> {
        @Override
        public List<Double> call() throws Exception {
            List<Double> statelList = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("Starting RestCallThread!!!!");
            int ctr = 0;
            while (true) {
                if (ctr > 10) {
                    latch.countDown();
                    System.out.println("Finished RestCallThread!!!!");
                    return statelList;
                }
                System.out.println("Adding to RestCallThread :: " + ctr);
                statelList.add(Math.random());
                ctr++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate...learned a lot from this post, especially the countdown latch approach... just a question though, aren't Executor Service a bit of an overkill in this case?  I don't know about that actually still reading info on that...but threads can do the job right?  Learning a lot from this.

Comment: Also, if I used the countdownlatch then does it mean that I could do away with the thread.join right?

Comment: Yes, if you use count down latch, then you don't need to use `Thread.join` However since we are using `Callable` instead of `Runnable` we need to have that `ExecutorService` in place.

Comment: Oh okay... I think I will have to work with using the Threads for now..but I like the idea of the latch.  Question though, what if the Rest Service takes some time and does not return...can I force the latch to countdown so that the other thread can do its job?

Comment: Yes you can give it a time out like so, `latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Sorry to bother you mate but one last question... you mention that if I used Shared Data Structure then I am opening myself to race condition.  So what if I used the latch approach then does it mean that I am protecting my List?  If not then how could I protect my List from experiencing race condition

Comment: Yes if you are using the latch, it is guaranteed that read operation of the data structure occurs after write completes. Hence there's no race condition. Otherwise you can use some concurrent collection such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or else you need to synchronize the access to the shared data structure using either a lock or condition objects.

Comment: Excellent mate...learned a lot from your answer.  Keep on rocking. More power!

Comment: If you are more interested in Threads in Java, I would recommend you to read this book by the author of the concurrent library: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321349601/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0321349601&linkCode=as2&tag=briangoetz-20&linkId=d1410b098c65f3549c71f5023b34b513